# best way to change colors of a solidcolorbrush

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, solidcolorbrush

I have a brush that is binded to the background of an element in my wpf app.

When I initialize it in the constructor, I do so accordingly:

```
MessageBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Now there are times in the code where I want to change the background to green. I have been doing it like so:

```
MessageBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
```

but this seems wrong to me. Message background itself is type System.Windows.Media.Brush. It does not appear to have any property like Color or Brush that would permit dynamically changing it.

Comment: `((SolidColorBrush)MessageBackground).Color = Colors.LightGreen;`

Comment: "this seems wrong to me" -- What do you mean "seems wrong"? Anything concrete, or just an indistinct sense of foreboding?

Comment: Why not simply change the type of the MessageBackground property to SolidColorBrush?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to cast the `MessageBackground` property to a `SolidColorBrush` to be able to set its `Color` property:

```
var brush = MessageBackground as SolidColorBrush;
if (brush != null)
    brush.Color = Colors.LightGreen;
```

This is not any better than simply setting the property to a new `SolidColorBrush` though so your current approach is perfectly fine.